# Magento upgrade 1.7 to 1.9.2.2 , product frontend giving 404

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404, e-commerce, magento-1.9

I upgraded my Multi-store magento from 1.7 to 1.9.2.2.
On frontend CMS , Categories etc are working fine. but product detail pages giving 404 error.
I reindexed all indexes.
refresh all caches but still same.
Can anyone help?

Comment: check your logs first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: its is programming related question , i specifically tagged it as magneto question , its related to magrnto model/observers but wm unable to find the issue , that's why posted.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the URL rewrite is to blame.  You may want to run the indexes via command line.
SSH Into the server and cd into the directory that has your magento code then use this command to run the indexes

php shell/indexer.php --reindexall

You may also want to clear you caches, and check the server logs for some hints.
404 is most certainly the URL rewrite causing the problem, so running the indexes via command line should fix that for you.